# Able to get my Docker Container onto Heroku but I have no idea how to access endpoints

Tags: docker, heroku

I've followed the directions here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime

And then I followed the quick instructions to allocate a dyno: https://medium.com/@MatheusCAS/deploying-docker-to-heroku-344985da5426

I'm now able to get the wonderful message that the app is running:

```
2018-04-04T23:13:48.082637+00:00 heroku[api.1]: Starting process with command `flask run --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5000`
2018-04-04T23:13:48.785247+00:00 heroku[api.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-04-04T23:13:50.342651+00:00 app[api.1]:  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2018-04-04T23:13:50.346134+00:00 app[api.1]:  * Restarting with stat
```

However I have legitimately *zero clue* how to access any of my defined endpoints! I want to say that the api is running within the container, but I can't "expose" it and its endpoints to the outside World. Most every URL I visit or `curl` just provides the **Application error** html response.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV TZ UTC
ADD ./requirements.txt /opt/code/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /opt/code
RUN mkdir -p /opt/logs && \
   mkdir -p /opt/media && \
  apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
  gcc \
  build-essential &&\
  pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt && \
  apt-get purge -y \
  gcc \
  build-essential && \
  apt-get clean autoclean && \
  apt-get autoremove -y && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/{apt,dpkg,cache,log}/
EXPOSE 5000
ENV FLASK_APP api_name/wsgi.py
ENV FLASK_CONFIG Dev
ENV FLASK_DEBUG 1
ADD . /opt/code/
RUN python /opt/code/setup.py develop
CMD ["flask", "run", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "5000"]
ARG SOME_ENV_VAR
ENV SOME_ENV_VAR "$SOME_ENV_VAR"
```

And my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - SOME_ENV_VAR=${SOME_ENV_VAR}
    container_name: api_name
    image: api_name
    volumes:
      - ../api-name:/opt/code
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

I realize that `EXPOSE 5000` isn't recognized by Heroku, could that be an issue? Should I try removing all port stuff, performing a build/push of the container?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

So I've created an additional `web:` service in my docker-compose.yml (literally copy&pasted the `api:` portion with changing name of the image), performed a build and pushed it to Heroku. Seems like things may be closer to actually working but I'm still unable to reach .. well, any endpoints. At the moment my logs are showing me:

```
2018-04-04T23:44:38.275695+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `flask run --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5000`
2018-04-04T23:44:40.252177+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2018-04-04T23:44:40.258019+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Restarting with stat
2018-04-04T23:44:40.694791+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Debugger is active!
2018-04-04T23:44:40.696554+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Debugger PIN: ###
2018-04-04T23:44:40.737185+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:55008/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2018-04-04T23:44:41.095223+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-04-04T23:44:41.199265+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Debugger is active!
2018-04-04T23:44:41.199497+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Debugger PIN: ###
```

Anyone got any ideas? Why does it seem to be running *two* servers?

Answer (score 1):

Your in luck!  The environment variable interpolation in docker-compose works pretty well. This should expose your endpoint.  It's the same technique you use in every heroku application.

```
ports:
  - "${PORT}:5000"
```

The endpoint will be served on port 80 of your application.

Comment: Still receiving an H12 timeout. I really think the problem is the `CMD` line in my Dockerfile. I should be running flask with the proper Heroku port, but I can't get it to work with the `$PORT` variable. It's driving me nuts.

Comment: I was going to say that was a strange way to spin up a dockerized app on heroku.  I deploy flask apps to heroku all the time. You just need a Procfile and then to get the port where you start your flask app:     port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))

Comment: I've come to realize that I was approaching it completely wrong since you can't build the container ON heroku (so having the Dockerfile read a dynamic port won't work) - instead I replaced the CMD line with one that just calls the app.py file which contains what you mentioned (an `app.run` call)

Comment: Oh right!  Now I see that in your compose file. I assumed you using the image in a docker repo (in the compose file), not building it!.  That would work, I think,

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards trying to access `$PORT` elsewhere than the `Dockerfile`. Don't want to think how many more days I would have been banging my head on this!

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured it out. My issue is that I embarrassingly didn't realize that I could never perform a `docker-compose build web` locally *WITH* remote Heroku environment variables! So obvious when I say it out loud but for whatever reason it was over my head yesterday.

*Anyway*, in order to remedy this and the issue of starting the server twice I changed out the `CMD` line in my `Dockerfile` from:

```
CMD ["flask", "run", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "5000"]
```

to:

```
CMD python my_api/app.py
```

While making sure to have the proper `app.run` located in that `app.py` file:

```
import os
port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

And bam! Everything works as it should!

Answer (score 0):

Having the Dockerfile read a dynamic port works as follows

CMD ["sh","-c","flask run --host 0.0.0.0 --port ${PORT}"]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).